# Unable to POST zip File to TeamsApp Endpoint using NodeJS

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I created a simple teams app, which works fine when sideloaded/uploaded manually to organization.
I want to use the endpoint : POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps. After getting the access token from the User, this error pops up in the request response :

```
    body: `{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Caller doesn't have permissions to publish to the Teams App catalog.","innerError":{"date":"2024-02-01T11:21:34","request-id":"xxxxx","client-request-id":"xxxxx"}}}`,
```

I have the required scope permissions, and my Application is registered in the Active Directory, for all Microsoft Accounts.

My code ->

```
const url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps';
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'app.zip');

    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
      console.error(`File not found: ${filePath}`);
      return null;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(filePath));

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${code}`,
      },
      formData: {
        file: {
          value: formData,
          options: {
            filename: 'file.zip',
            contentType: 'application/zip',
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

The same bearer code works for other requests, seems to only cause issues with this one.
Please note, the required permissions have been granted, even Admin level.

Also, the endpoint GET /appCatalogs/teamsApps/ and DELETE /appCatalogs/teamsApps/{id} works as well.

Comment: Could you please verify whether you have one of the following delegated permissions or not? `AppCatalog.Submit` `AppCatalog.ReadWrite.All` `Directory.ReadWrite.All`
 Additionally, ensure that the user has the necessary administrative privileges to publish to the Teams App catalog. The documentation also mentions that only Global Administrators can call this API. If you have already granted the required permissions and the user has the necessary administrative privileges, there might be an issue with the code or the access token.